# Is it okay to post nudity if it's in the film/TV show?

Tags: discussion

Sparked by [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/could-daenerys-be-brought-back-according-to-the-rules-of-death) post where Daenery's breasts <s>are</s> were being shown.

Even if there's a justifiable reason (whatever that may be) to include nudity from a film/TV show in a post, should the OP still take the appropriate measures to censor it? Or should the screenshot be omitted all together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes **only if it's absolutely necessary**. In those situations I would either

- put the image in a spoiler
- just link to the image

and in both cases give a warning that it's NSFW (Not Safe For Work). For example:

---

NSFW image, exposed breasts with nipples

> ![Image of boobs][1]

---

Of course you should endeavor to avoid it as best you can by finding a more SFW  (Safe For Work) image. if the question makes just as much sense without the image (i.e. it does not rely on the image being there) then it would be safe to just remove the image.

Comment: That's how we did few time before too, anyways nice answer